# Amount of total valid strings with multiple constraints

Tags: combinatorics, string-count

There is a string that has five potential letters (A,B,C,D,E). However, we have some constraints:

1. Each unique ordering of the string is a different passcode. Letters can be used more than once or not at all.
2. No letter can be adjacent to itself anywhere on the passcode (A - A - B - C - D is not valid)
3. No letter can be used more than twice.

How many valid orders are there?

---

Initial thoughts:

So we have 5 slots: So in the first slot it doesn’t matter which string so there are 5 potential options. In the second spot we have 4 potential options, since we can’t repeat the one in the first. In the third we also have 4 potential options … etc.

However, I know this is wrong because I’m not really considering the max of 2 letters allowed. How would I solve this?

Answer (score 12):

Polya's Theorem and a heavy dose of group theory are generally used to solve such problems, but in this relatively simple example all you need to do is draw a diagram to keep track of letters as they appear.

In scanning a word from left to right, let "A" denote the first letter observed (no matter what it might be, so there are $5$ possible values for it), let "B" denote the next *distinct* letter observed, and so on.  Let's keep track of the prefix of the word as we go along.

Thus, at the outset, the word is empty:  .  There are $5$ possible transitions to the prefix `A`.  From there, *the transition to `AA` is forbidden.*  Thus, you *must* observe a distinct letter `B` and there are $4$ possibilities to reach `AB` from `A`.

Continuing in this fashion, we construct a *directed acyclic graph* of the sequence of prefix patterns.  By proceeding systematically, it is straightforward to write down.  Here, I have indicated the transitions with arrows and the number of possibilities in each transition is placed above its arrow.

[image]

The round circle at right designates a valid word.  I haven't shown all the distinct possibilities for the last transition, but only the counts, which are readily determined from the rules.  For instance, neither `A` or `C` may follow `ABAC` (there are already two of the first and we can't have one `C` follow another), leaving three possible letters corresponding to two patterns `ABACB` and `ABACD`.

The total number of possibilities is found by summing all distinct paths from the initial   to the final word.  The possibilities along a path are found by multiplying the values on its edges, *because each transition is independent of the preceding ones.*

For instance, words of the form `ABCA*`, where `*` is anything but an `A`, correspond to the path  -->`A`-->`AB`-->`ABC`-->`ABCA`-->`*` and there are $5\times 4\times 3 \times 1 \times 4 = 240$ such words.

So, systematically working from the uppermost paths to the lowermost (and collecting common prefixes using the distributive law), the answer is

$$5\times 4\times(1\times(1\times 3 + 3\times 3) + 3\times (1\times 4 + 1\times 4 + 2\times 4)) = 1200.$$

---

To verify this, you may compute the answer by brute-force enumeration provided the number of possible words in the alphabet (here, $5^5 = 3125$) is not prohibitively large.  Here is an `R` implementation.

```R
s <- 5    # Alphabet length
k <- 5    # Word length
kmax <- 2 # Max occurrences of any letter

X <- do.call(expand.grid, lapply(seq_len(k), \(x) seq_len(s)))
i <- apply(X, 1, \(x) max(tabulate(x, s)) <= kmax)
j <- rowSums(X[, -1] == X[, -k]) > 0
nrow(X[i & !j, ])
```

This calculation takes no time at all.  It took a few seconds when applied to five-letter words from an alphabet of 26 letters, for instance, returning $10,140,000$ (out of the $26^5 = 11,881,376$ possible words).

---

#### Edit

For larger problems, and for studying the patterns, we can exploit the recursive structure of this "prefix DAG" to write a function that generates the DAG and computes the answer.

To illustrate how this might work, here is an `R` solution using the (relatively simple) functions defined below.

```R
Build(length = 5) |> Filter(f = valid) |> Size(alphabet = 5, print.level = 4)
```

The `print.level` argument prints intermediate output.  You will recognize it as the "rolling up" of partial sums as the DAG is traversed backwards from right to left, culminating in the answer:

```
1 2 1 2 :  3 
1 2 1 3 :  9 
1 2 1 :  12 
1 2 3 1 :  4 
1 2 3 2 :  4 
1 2 3 4 :  8 
1 2 3 :  48 
1 2 :  240 
1 :  1200
```

Unlike the brute-force approach, because this solution only has to generate the *patterns* of the words in this language, it is much faster.  (It represents the patterns with numbers 1, 2, 3, ... instead of letters A, B, C, ... .)  The calculation for the alphabet of 26 letters, for example, takes no longer than the calculation for 5 letters.  It's the same formula but with different transition counts on the edges.

```R
#
# Utility function to remove empty elements of a list.
#
clean. <- function(x) {
  x[!sapply(x, \(y) is.null(y) | length(y) == 0)]
}
#
# Create a DAG of all possible patterns of words of length `length`.
#
Build <- function(length) {
  build <- function(p, n) {
    if (n <= 0) return(NULL)
    children = clean.(lapply(seq_len(max(p) + 1), \(k) build(c(p, k), n - 1)))
    obj <- list(Head = p, Children = children)
    class(obj) <- "DAG"
    obj
  }
  build(1, length)
}
#
# Filter a DAG.
# `f` is applied to the heads of the DAG, returning TRUE for any prefix
# that occurs in the language.
#
Filter <- function(D, f = \(x) TRUE) {
  if (isTRUE(f(D$Head))) {
    D$Children <- clean.(lapply(D$Children, Filter, f = f))
  } else D <- NULL
  D
}
#
# Compute the size of a language described by a prefix DAG.
#
Size <- function(D, alphabet = 0, print.level = -1) {
  if(is.null(D) || length(D) == 0) return(0)
  x <- D$Head
  n <- length(x)
  k <- tail(x, 1)
  N <- ifelse(k <= max(c(0, head(x, n-1))), 1, max(0, alphabet + 1 - k))
  C <- if(length(D$Children) == 0) 1 else {
    sum(unlist(lapply(D$Children, Size, alphabet = alphabet, 
                      print.level = print.level)))
  }
  if(length(x) <= print.level) cat(paste0(x), ": ", N * C, "\n")
  N * C
}
#
# List the prefixes of a language (diagnostic).
#
Prefixes <- function(D, f = \(s) paste0(s, collapse = "")) {
  if(is.null(D)) return(list())
  c(list(f(D$Head)), lapply(D$Children, Prefixes))
}
```